# regex - wrap all integers in double quotes

Tags: regex

I want to turn this string;

`0000,0767,"078", 0785, "0723",23487, 345 , 07334`

Into this string;

`"0000","0767","078", "0785", "0723","23487", "345" , "07334"`

This is the closest I can get to it, I always get a bit confused with negative lookups and such when it comes to regex.

`[^"\d,]?(\d+)` and a replace with `"$1"` - https://regex101.com/r/qVQYA7/1

unfortunately this results in double wrapped quotes for integers that already have double quotes around them, like so;

`"0000","0767",""078"","0785", ""0723"","23487","345" ,"07334"`

The pseudo logic is; *look for any integers that **don't** already have double quotes around them, and add double quotes. Leave any spacing in between commas as is.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use lookarounds in your regex to avoid matching quoted numbers:

```
(?<!")(\b\d+\b)(?!")
```

[Updated Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/qVQYA7/2)

**RegEx Breakup:**

```
(?<!")   # Negative lookbehind to skip the match if previous character is "
(        # captured group #1 open
   \b    # assert word boundary
   \d+   # match 1 or more digits
   \b    # assert word boundary
)        # captured group close
(?!")    # Negative lookahead to skip the match if next character is "
```

If you're using PCRE then you can use this PCRE verb:

```
"\d+"(*SKIP)(*F)|(\d+)
```

Comment: This works perfectly and fits all my data values. thanks.

Answer (score 5):

You can simply search for `"?(\d+)"?` and replace it with `"$1"`.
If there are " present, they are matched but not contained in the group.

Comment: This would be a simple solution, however I neglected to add to my example string that there are some instances like so `"+232987"` which in this case does not work. However as your code does answer my example just fine, you still get an upvote from me.

Answer (score 2):

Let's say that in your case each sequence of numbers should be followed by comma `,` or positioned at the end of the string.
 Use the following regex:

```
(\d+)\s*?(?=,|$)
```

https://regex101.com/r/qVQYA7/3

Comment: Good answer, fits the data I need, but I can only accept one answer. ;)

Comment: @Novocaine,  that's Ok