# Wrap integers in quotes from json data

Tags: json, regex

I created [this question yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40110706/regex-wrap-all-integers-in-double-quotes)

I've since realised there are actually a few other bits of data that cause issues with the solutions I received. Hence, I thought it best to make a new question

Take the following example data;

`"87",0000,0767,"078",0785,"0723",23487, "061 904 5284","17\/10\/2016","some.name.789@hotmail.com"`

Using the accepted solution form above `(?<!")(\b\d+\b)(?!")`

The date string ends up having the middle number in between the two `\/` wrapped, the number in quotes with spaces breaks as well as the email address.
The issues can be seen here: https://regex101.com/r/qVQYA7/6

**My Solution**

The following does seem to work for me, however it seems a bit messy. I have a feeling there's a much more succinct way to achieve the same result;

`,(?<!("|\/|\\))(\b\d+\b)(?!("|\/|\\|( \d)))` Replace with `,"$2"`

https://regex101.com/r/qVQYA7/5

**EDIT:**

@Federico this screenshot shows that spaces before or after commas breaks the replace;
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By reading your both questions, what I understand is that you want to wrap in double quots some numbers that aren't, so for this I can come up with a simple regex like this:

```
(?<=,)(\d+)(?=,)
```

With the replacement string: `"$1"`

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/qVQYA7/7)**

[image]

Update: after you updated the question, here I put the update for the answer. You can use this regex instead:

```
(?<=,)\s*(\d+)\s*(?=,)
```

Comment: This is very close. One thing I cannot be sure of is that there will or will not be a space before or after the comma. It's very likely that there will be no spaces, but as I'm not in control of the source data, I'd like to allow for spaces. Your example, doesn't work if spaces vary. `(?<=[, ])(\d+)(?=[, ])` seems to fix that, but I'm not sure if that's bad practice.

Comment: Ah, wait, that doesn't work for the `061 904 5284` number

Comment: @Novocaine what is the expected result for that number, it is already wrapped in quotes

Comment: That number should be left as is, with my attempted tweak, that number ends up with additional quotes added inside it.

Comment: @Novocaine I'm not following you, my regex does't touch that number, I added the screenshot where you can see only the match numbers. Can you add a link showing what is not working

Comment: I've added a screenshot to my question. The issues occurs if there are spaces in between the comma and the numbers. I cannot guarantee there will not be any spaces here, so the code has to allow for them. I attempted to fix that with the regex in my first comment, but that attempt caused the issue with the number in my second comment.

Comment: Ah of course, that makes sense. I should have tried that! Thanks very much!